# How can I use regex to select first six characters only when there are 12 characters present

Tags: regex

I have some regex that selects the first 6 characters and last six characters. `^.{0,6} .{6}$`.

I basically only want it to select the first/last 6 characters if there are 12 characters.

Eg. select nothing if `202203`, but select the first six characters if `202201202203`.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern `^.{0,6} .{6}$` matches 0-6 characters with this part `.{0,6}` and matches a mandatory space before the last 6 characters which is not present in *202201202203*

You can use 2 capture group instead, and then you can select if you want the first or last 6 characters.

```
^(.{6})(.{6})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LTxgf0/1)

Note that the `.` can also match a space.

Answer (score 0):

This works if 12 characters is your minimum *and* maximum by using look ahead:

```
^.{6}(?=.{6}).{6}$
```